# GIF Spinner is left Aligned, how to make it centered align through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following DIV in HTML:

```
<div id="progress" class="progress">
    <img src="Content/themes/base/images/progress.gif" />
    <br />
    <span>LOADING... </span>
</div>
```

The CSS class definition is:

```
.progress
{
text-align: center;
}
```

On Page load, progress spinner loads in center of screen but when I hide and then show this spinner, it is always left aligned.

Following is the code to stop the spinner:

```
document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "none";
```

And to show it again (here it becomes left align to screen):

```
document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "inline";
```

What am i missing??

Comment: you can do this thru css itself.. if possible try display:block; margin:0 auto; for progress class..

Comment: @Kiran Tried but not working!!

Comment: Post your fiddle link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I modified css class as follows:

```
.progress
{
text-align: center;
display: none;
}
```

And used JQuery show/hide methods:

```
$(".progress").show();
$(".progress").hide();
```

Working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

`text-align` only applies to block containers (which a div is by default).

Use `display: block` not `display: inline`

```
…style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to hide and show the spinner, because you don't want to change any of the css, because making the the style in-line aligns it left, you could also use

```
document.getElementById("progress").style.display="box";
```

and it wont apply the left align.